# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

When I execute command `npm run serve` there is above error:

```
2:21 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetify/lib/framework'. 'C:/Users/valut/source/repos/BricksDryierClient/client-app/node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vuetify` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vuetify/lib/framework';`       
    1 | import Vue from 'vue';
  > 2 | import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
      |                     ^
    3 | 
    4 | Vue.use(Vuetify);
    5 |
```

I tried to add `vuetify` to `compilerOptions.types` in `tsconfig.json`, but it isn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should change the second line in `src/plugins/vuetify.ts` from:

```ts
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
```

to:

```ts
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
```

Comment: Note that this is the default behavior of the Vuetify plugin. Which can lead to extra confusion from googlers. Just a comment for future viewers.

Comment: same thing happen to me, what I did was stopped the development server and started again solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found my self using advanced option when choosing a vuetify preset("Configure (advanced)"), then I tried "Default (recommended)" option to recreate the project and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it this way

`import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';` in your "main.js".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).